# ReactStrap: When the dropdown list is long, the user cannot see the last values

Tags: css, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, reactstrap

I have this dropdown list:
[image]

As you see it takes-up the whole screen and some items are hidden.
Here's the code:

```
  const statusSearchDropDownValues = (
  <Row className="align-items-center">
    <Col col="6" sm="4" md="2" xl className="mb-3 mb-xl-0">
      <Dropdown
        isOpen={this.state.statusSearchropDownOpen}
        toggle={() => {
          this.toggleStatusSearchDropDown();
        }}
      >
        <DropdownToggle className="my-dropdown" caret>
          {this.state.statusSearchDropDownValue}
        </DropdownToggle>
        <DropdownMenu>
          <DropdownItem>
            {" "}
            <div
              value="operation_cree"
              onClick={this.changeStatusSearchDropDownValue}
            >
              Operation créée
            </div>
          </DropdownItem>
          {/* Multiple other DropdownItems */}
        </DropdownMenu>
      </Dropdown>
    </Col>
  </Row>
);
```

Since it's long, the user cannot see the last values.
I have searched how to make it scrollable. But, I didn't find anything.
Any suggestions as to how to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add this style to the DropdownMenu element:

```
...
 <DropdownMenu style={{maxHeight:"200px", overflow:"scroll"}}>
...
```

Comment: Thanks that worked just make sure to use the quotes: style={{ maxHeight: "500px", overflow: "scroll" }}